# Windows Forms & Actual Installer - Package being reported as malware

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

We're building a proof of concept windows application based on Windows Forms.

We plan to offer the package for beta testing to a small focus group but whenever one tries to download the app from our website Google Chrome / Internet Explorer report that the software may be malware.

I am not an actual desktop software developer, C# is just an hobby and I have no clue on how "sign" the software as legit. Any advice from someone doing this on a daily basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are some of the code signing tools I've used so far:

- [SignTool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of Microsoft
- [DigiCertUtility](https://www.digicert.com/util/)

Those code signing tools are free and there are a lot of it out there but you need to buy digital certificate to sign your code or your installer to make your software trusted. Before you can buy a certificate they will verify few credentials about you or your company because they will put it in your certificate as trusted publisher.